# Running scripts with special conditions in Atom

Tags: common-lisp, atom-editor

I used to use the build system in Sublime text where I could add my own customize build systems. For example, for CLisp, I created a build system as such:

```
{
    "cmd": ["clisp", "-q", "-modern", "-L", "french", "$file"],
    "selector": "source.lisp"   
}
```

Similarly, I had a custom one for C:

```
{
"cmd" : ["gcc $file_name -Wall -o ${file_base_name} && ./${file_base_name}"],
"selector" : "source.c",
"shell": true,
"working_dir" : "$file_path"
}
```

How can I do this in Atom?

Comment: Please come tell use about your experience when you're done on https://www.reddit.com/r/lisp/ :)

Answer (score 2):

For tthat task atom has a nice package called Atom Build package, you can find it here: https://github.com/noseglid/atom-build

It is using javascript here is an example for:

```
module.exports = {
  cmd: 'make',
  name: 'Makefile',
  sh: true,
  functionMatch: function (output) {
    const enterDir = /^make\[\d+\]: Entering directory '([^']+)'$/;
    const error = /^([^:]+):(\d+):(\d+): error: (.+)$/;
    // this is the list of error matches that atom-build will process
    const array = [];
    // stores the current directory
    var dir = null;
    // iterate over the output by lines
    output.split(/\r?\n/).forEach(line => {
      // update the current directory on lines with `Entering directory`
      const dir_match = enterDir.exec(line);
      if (dir_match) {
        dir = dir_match[1];
      } else {
        // process possible error messages
        const error_match = error.exec(line);
        if (error_match) {
          // map the regex match to the error object that atom-build expects
          array.push({
            file: dir ? dir + '/' + error_match[1] : error_match[1],
            line: error_match[2],
            col: error_match[3],
            message: error_match[4]
          });
        }
      }
    });
    return array;
  }
};
```